# Does 防具による攻撃 mean "attacks with armor" or "attacks depending on armor"

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

This is a vhs promotional video about a videogame.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUhd8qoQl6E&t=4m55s

さらにタクティクスオウガでは、ユニットの武器や防具による攻撃、魔法攻撃、各ユニットの特性を生かした攻撃など、バラエティーに富んだアクションをもフルアニメーションで構成。

My question is, if 武器や防具による攻撃 means "weapon and armor attacks", how can "armor" attack?

Comment: Have you ever been hit with a shield? :) I haven't but I imagine it wouldn't feel good.

Comment: @Leebo Can shields be used as weapons in Tactics Ogre LUCT? I know for a fact, after having beaten FFT 3 times, that a player can't attack with their shield, at least in that game.

Comment: This just in. Apparently, after hours of searching, it appears that in this game you CAN use shields as weapons. I'll be damned. https://tacticsogre.fandom.com/wiki/Shields#:~:text=Shields%20are%20an%20a%20set,they%20are%20capable%20of%20damage.&text=Light%20%2D%20Can%20be%20equipped%20by,2%2Dhanded%20weapons%20anyway).

Comment: There are at least some games in which having certain pieces of equipment on lets you use special moves - that's what I would have assumed this refers to

Comment: "armor" can also refer to a tank in English... but it seems unlikely here

Comment: Yeah but this game doesn't use tanks or armored vehicles.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's "attacks using armors", or more specifically, shields. From [this blog article](https://anno-yuki.hatenablog.com/entry/39063808):

> また、盾は防具としてだけでなく、剣や斧などのように射程距離１マスの近接武器として使うことも可能。盾を構えて体当たりをくらわす、いわゆる「シールドバッシュ」ですね。
> 与えるダメージは極めて小さいですが、相手の体重（装備重量）が軽ければ１マスぶん突き飛ばすことができます。

Some other games (eg [Dark Souls](https://youtu.be/29aurIGkUE4)) have this feature.